# Alter admin theme

Tags: 8, theming

I would like to make a small change in the `admin/structure/taxonomy/` page.

I need to add one more operation to the edit button on the page.

Its the `template_preprocess_links()` function I need to alter I believe. I have created a sub theme of the admin theme (Seven). Set it default admin theme. Created `mytheme_preprocess_links()` function but it does not run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add/alter entity operations you can use [`hook_entity_operation_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_operation_alter/8.5.x):

```
function hook_entity_operation_alter(array &$operations, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

  if ($entity instanceof \Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface) {
    $operations['foo_operation'] = [
      'title' => 'Foo',
      'url' => \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('bar', ['taxonomy_term' => $entity->id()]),
      'weight' => 10,
    ];
  }
}
```